# While loop : get first div to add active class

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

i want to add active class in while loop first div.
but its not working

```
$ban_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banners");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ban_sql)){
      echo '<div class="item ';
        if($row <= 1) {
            echo 'active ">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '">';
        }
       echo '<img src="'.$row['banner_img'].'"/> </div>';
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ban_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banners");
$count = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ban_sql)){
      echo '<div class="item ';
        if($count == 0) {
            echo 'active ">';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '">';
        }
       echo '<img src="'.$row['banner_img'].'"/> </div>';
$count++;
      }
```

$row will contain a MySQL rowset so you need a separate variable to store the current row iteration count.

Comment: only one more change ($row ==0) is replaced with ($count == 0)